# Smooth movement in Java2D top down game

Tags: java, 2d

I am sure that others have had the same problem but after a significant amount of googling, I was unable to find anything completely relevant.

I am working on a 2D top-down game using Java2D. I have separate rendering and physics threads.
Movement is mouse-based, and calculations take the following form:

```
    isMoving = false;
    // Sets initial distance moved to 0
    playersMoveX = 0;
    playersMoveY = 0;

    // If player clicks, determines the distance to click
    if (MainGame.movement)
    {
        distanceX = MouseClass.changeInX;
        distanceY = MouseClass.changeInY;

        moveMarker();
    }

    // Prevents divide by zero error, and prevents variables from becoming negative
    if (distanceX < 0)
        distanceX = 0;
    if (distanceY < 0)
        distanceY = 0;
    if (distanceX == 0 && distanceY == 0)
        return;

    // Sets the speed that the player moves (player moves a distance of moveFactor each cycle)
    if (Player.sprint)
        moveFactor = 2;
    else
        moveFactor = 1;

    double sumDistance = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(distanceX, 2) + Math.pow(distanceY, 2));
    double deltaX = (moveFactor * distanceX / sumDistance) * dT; 
    double deltaY = (moveFactor * distanceY / sumDistance) * dT;
    // Determines distance moved in x and y directions by using the ration of distanceX to distanceY
    if (MouseClass.mousePositionX > GUI.fullScreenWidth / 2 - 1 && preventCollision(0, npcs, buildings, objects))
    {
        playersMoveX += deltaX;
    }
    else if (preventCollision(1, npcs, buildings, objects))
    {
        playersMoveX -= deltaX;
    }
    if (MouseClass.mousePositionY > GUI.fullScreenHeight / 2 + 5 && preventCollision(2, npcs, buildings, objects))
    {
        playersMoveY += deltaY;
    }
    else if (preventCollision(3, npcs, buildings, objects))
    {
        playersMoveY -= deltaY;
    }
    // Accounts for movement in the distance to the click
    distanceX -= deltaX;
    distanceY -= deltaY;
    if (deltaX != 0 || deltaY != 0)
        isMoving = true;
```

Then, I subtract playersMoveX from every object's x, and playersMoveY from every object's y.
I tried adjusting the rate of physics calculations, going above 80 'frames' per second when it only renders at 60, no change.

**THE PROBLEM**

Objects bounce around when the player moves. The Player is centered in the screen, so everything else moves in relation to it. Since I am using doubles, the way I handle rounding is always rounding down with Math.floor()

Answer (score 0):

> I subtract playersMoveX from every object's x, and playersMoveY from every object's y.

That does not seem like good design, and is likely to be the source of your problem. Look into the translation methods in the `Graphics` class (I assume that's what you use to draw) because what you really want is to translate the perspective, not every possible thing:

```
g.translate(playersMoveX, playerMoveY); // or some variation to center the player
```